# Return amount of labels in the x-axis matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Are there any built-in methods that I can use to count the number of labels there are in my plot?
For example: `top_words.min()` will return how many times a word must occur in order to be shown in the bar chart. Looking for a similar method, but only for the labels.  Picture of the bar chart is linked below my function.

I am plotting words into a bar chart using this function

```
def plot_top_words(tweets, num_word_instances, top_words):
    tdm_df = create_term_document_matrix(tweets, min_df=2)
    word_frequencies = tdm_df[[x for x in tdm_df.columns if len(x) > 1]].sum()
    sorted_words = word_frequencies.sort_values(ascending=False)
    top_sorted_words = sorted_words[:num_word_instances]
    top_sorted_words[:top_words].plot.bar()
    return top_sorted_words
```

The output I get with below input is:

[image: picture of bar chart and output here]

```
top_words = plot_top_words(clean_tweets, 50, 10)
top_words
```

The return value I am looking for in this example is 10.

Comment: Do `ax = top_sorted...plot.bar()` and then `ax.get_xticks()` give you the list of ticks. In the case of bar plot, however, this is exactly `top_sorted_word[:top_words].index`.

Comment: @QuangHoang ill try this later today, thanks!